# UITableView for Forms Crashes

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableViewController that I'm using for a form. Each cell has a UILabel and a UITextField. When I tap on a UITextField, the keyboard comes up, then I scroll down and the cell goes off screen, when I tap on another UITextField, the app crashes.

**This is my cell subclass.**

```
@implementation EditorFieldCell

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

        [self.contentView addSubview:self.nameLabel];
        [self.contentView addSubview:self.textField];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setName:(NSString *)name
{
    _name = name;

    CGRect frame = self.nameLabel.frame;
    frame.size.width = roundf([_name sizeWithFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17.0f]].width);
    self.nameLabel.frame = frame;

    frame = self.textField.frame;
    frame.size.width = self.frame.size.width - 16.0f - 14.0f - 14.0f - self.nameLabel.frame.size.width;
    frame.origin.x = 16.0f + 14.0f + self.nameLabel.frame.size.width;
    self.textField.frame = frame;

    self.nameLabel.text = _name;
}

- (void)setPlaceholder:(NSString *)placeholder
{
    _placeholder = placeholder;

    self.textField.placeholder = placeholder;
}

- (void)setText:(NSString *)text
{
    _text = text;

    self.textField.text = text;
}

- (UILabel*)nameLabel
{
    if (_nameLabel)
    {
        return _nameLabel;
    }

    _nameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(16.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, self.frame.size.height)];
    _nameLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17.0f];
    return _nameLabel;
}

- (UITextField*)textField
{
    if (_textField)
    {
        return _textField;
    }

    _textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, self.frame.size.height)];
    _textField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0f];
    _textField.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
    _textField.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceDark;
    return _textField;
}

@end
```

And here is my table subclass.

```
@interface ManageWineViewController ()

@end

@implementation ManageWineViewController

- (id)init
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    if (self) {
        self.title = @"Manage Wine";
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(done)];
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Save" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(save)];

        NSMutableArray *data = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        NSMutableDictionary *section = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        NSMutableArray *sectionData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        [sectionData addObject:@{@"name": @"Estate", @"placeholder": @""}];
        [sectionData addObject:@{@"name": @"Wine", @"placeholder": @""}];
        [sectionData addObject:@{@"name": @"Vintage", @"placeholder": @"", @"keyboardType": [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad]}];
        [section setObject:sectionData forKey:@"data"];

        [data addObject:section];

        section = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        sectionData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        [sectionData addObject:@{@"name": @"Type"}];
        [sectionData addObject:@{@"name": @"Style", @"placeholder": @"Select a Style", @"options": @[@"", @"Red", @"White", @"Rosé", @"Sparkling", @"Saké", @"Dessert, Sherry, and Port"]}];
        [sectionData addObject:@{@"name": @"Appellation", @"placeholder": @""}];
        [section setObject:sectionData forKey:@"data"];

        [data addObject:section];

        section = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        sectionData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        [sectionData addObject:@{@"name": @"Alcohol %", @"placeholder": @"", @"keyboardType": [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad]}];
        [section setObject:sectionData forKey:@"data"];

        [data addObject:section];

        self.data = data;

        self.inputTexts = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:@{@"0": @"",
                                                                            @"1": @"",
                                                                            @"2": @"",
                                                                            @"10": @"",
                                                                            @"11": @"",
                                                                            @"12": @"",
                                                                            @"20": @""}];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)done
{
    [self.currentTextField resignFirstResponder];

    [self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)save
{
    [self done];
}

- (void)hidePicker
{
    [self.selectActionSheet dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return self.data.count;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return ((NSArray*)[[self.data objectAtIndex:section] objectForKey:@"data"]).count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSDictionary *cellInfo = [((NSArray*)[[self.data objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectForKey:@"data"]) objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"EditorCell";
    EditorFieldCell *cell = (EditorFieldCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (!cell)
    {
        cell = [[EditorFieldCell alloc] init];
    }

    cell.textField.tag = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i%i", indexPath.section, indexPath.row] integerValue];
    cell.textField.delegate = self;

    cell.name = cellInfo[@"name"];
    cell.placeholder = cellInfo[@"placeholder"];
    cell.text = [self.inputTexts objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", cell.textField.tag]];

    if (cellInfo[@"keyboardType"])
    {
        cell.textField.keyboardType = [cellInfo[@"keyboardType"] integerValue];
    }
    else
    {
        cell.textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
    }

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
}

#pragma mark - UITextFieldDelegate methods
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    self.currentTextField = textField;

    if (textField.tag == 11)
    {
        //show select
        NSArray *options = [[[[self.data objectAtIndex:1] objectForKey:@"data"] objectAtIndex:1] objectForKey:@"options"];
        self.selectTextField = textField;
        self.selectOptions = options;

        [textField resignFirstResponder];

        self.selectActionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];

        CGRect pickerFrame = CGRectMake(0, 40, 0, 0);

        self.selectPickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:pickerFrame];
        self.selectPickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
        self.selectPickerView.dataSource = self;
        self.selectPickerView.delegate = self;

        [self.selectActionSheet addSubview:self.selectPickerView];
        [self.selectActionSheet showInView:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow]];
        [self.selectActionSheet setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 485)];
    }
}
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    [self.inputTexts setObject:textField.text forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", textField.tag]];
    return YES;
}

@end
```

The error that I am getting with the crash is:

```
*** -[EditorFieldCell _didChangeToFirstResponder:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x155f6e20
```

This is iOS 7 (and will only support iOS 7) if that helps.

Comment: Some object is released and you are try to access that object. Enable NSZombieEnabled in profile and also add exception breakpoint to know exact object which is released.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not initialising `EditorFieldCell` with reuse identifier.

```
   EditorFieldCell *cell = (EditorFieldCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

This condition will false.

```
   if (!cell)
     {
         cell = [[EditorFieldCell alloc] init];
     }
```

Try to create cell with reuseIdentifier

```
cell = [[EditorFieldCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                          reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

And write this in EditorFieldCell.m

```
-(id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {

    if (self == [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier]) {
           self.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

           [self.contentView addSubview:self.nameLabel];
           [self.contentView addSubview:self.textField];
    }

}
```

Comment: That did it! Not sure why, though. So I was always creating a new cell, not reusing old ones. But why would that cause this crash?